# How would I get Apple to list a calendar for people to subscribe at apple.com?

Tags: calendar, apple-inc

Apple lists about 140 Calendars you can subscribe to - some quite obscure looking, others quite obvious like federal holidays for large countries with large Apple customer bases. I don't see any way to alert Apple to a calendar and wondered if there were any sort of mechanism to provide a format for Apple to evaluate and possible publish.

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/index_abc.html

Are downloads something registered developers can seed or how would I publish a calendar and get it listed by Apple on their downloads site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It appears that this functionality has been removed.**

There used to be a sidebar box with the ability to contact Apple regarding adding your work to any of the download lists on Apple.com. However, this box no longer appears on the page.

[image]

Also, the linked page from the old submit link in the box above no longer appears to be functional:

- https://adcweb.apple.com/downloads/

[image]

This seems to match the fact that no new calendars have been uploaded for years.

[image]

Comment: Cool - a non answer that gives context and confirms the issue is always welcome. Thanks.